# Calculate rates from previous month based on current month in order to make then visually comparable

Tags: powerbi, dax

Maybe this is an easy one but since I’m very new in DAX and PowerBI I can’t figure it out. My database has daily data ranging from MAY/17 to JUN/17 (and it’ll still going in the future). It has information of DATE, DAY, YRMTH (year-month), QT_APRV (approved customers) and QT_TOTAL (total consumers). Sample below (using Excel just to be quicker):

[image: Sample table]

I wanted to create in PowerBI a bar chart with QT_TOTAL per day and a line chart with approved rate of consumer. For the rate, I used:

```
APPRV_RT = SUM(database[QT_APRV]/SUM(database[QT_TOTAL])
```

And then, selecting only a month by time in the chart (just like I want), I have:

[image: chart1]

Perfect, but now I want to create a new line chart, showing the approved rate in each respective day of the last month. Using my example, when june data are select, the first line chart has to show the daily approved rate of june AND the other the approved rate of may, in order to make it comparable (june1 -> may1; june12 -> may12 and so on). Here’s what I want:

[image]

How to make this automatically, in order to make each month comparable with the previous? I thought about some DAX formula involving a sum with filtering current month minus 1, I don’t know how to do it.

Any ideas?

UPDATE (07/08/2017)
I tried what Rasmus Dybkjær suggested me, and I thing I'm in the right path.

```
APPROVED_RATE_PREVIOUS_MONTH = CALCULATE([APPROVED_RATE_CURRENT_MONTH];PARALLELPERIOD(dCalendario[DataBase];-1;MONTH))
```

However, it returned the approved rate from the previous month as a whole (67,0% in May), not each day as I wanted:

[image: PowerBI - Approved rate]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the DAX function called PARALLELPERIOD() for this purpose. The PARALLELPERIOD() function takes a date column and shifts it a number of periods back or forward.

For example, you could use it like this to calculate your approved rate shifted one month back:

```
ApprovedRateLM = 
    CALCULATE(
        DIVIDE(
            SUM(database[QT_APRV]),
            SUM(database[QT_TOTAL])
        ), 
    PARALLELPERIOD(database[Date],-1,month)
    )
```

Note that it is important that your [Date] column contains a date type. Otherwise the PARALLELPERIOD function will not work.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I tried your suggestion, but still not exactly what I want (I'll put the result in my post).